# Scions, scions du bois

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

I'm listening to the comptines, while "Scions, scions du bois"'s lyrics is a bit confusing:

> Scion, scions, scions du bois,
>   Pour la mère, pour la mère,
>   Scion, scions, scions du bois,
>   Pour la mère à Nicolas,
>   Qu'a cassé ses sabots
>   En mille morceaux !

what does it mean, the last two lines? "Qu'a cassé ses sabots en mille morceaux !" -- is it "who (Nicolas's mother) broke his hooves/clogs into a thousand pieces!"

I don't quite understand why the mother would break the hooves or clogs to a thousand pieces? and why it's in a song of sawing wood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Sabots' is never hooves when you're talking about people, it's wooden shoes/aka clogs.  And @jiliagre is right that 'la mere Nicolas' means 'Mrs Nicolas', not actually anyone's mother, just an older woman, presumably married.  It's an older turn of phrase, and not literary, but still in use. As to a thousand pieces rather than just two, it's a common exageration.

So, keeping these points in mind.. what this boils down to is

> ```
> Let's saw, let's saw some wood 
> for mrs, for mrs 
> Let's saw, let's saw some wood 
> for mrs nicolas 
> who broke her clogs 
> in a thousand pieces
> Here are the pieces!
> ```

Nothing the least bit mysterious about someone breaking her clogs (and they do break, for those of you who've never worn them, although admittedly rarely both at once) and sawing some wood to make her another.

Comment: There is a problem in translating "mère" by "Mrs". A Harrap dictionary gives for "la mère Martin" the translation "old Mrs Martin" or "old mother Martin"; just "Mrs" is changing things too much.

Comment: Your problem, not mine :-).  I'm not a dictionary, I'm only bilingual.

Comment: I don't quite get your point! Does bilingualism entail the banishment of the dictionaries? Quite a novel notion!

Answer (score 6):

Not knowing the song, I guess "la mère à Nicolas/qu'a cassé ses sabots" may be confusing because it is a rather familiar turn of phrase.

A more standard turn would be:

> la mère de Nicolas, qui a cassé ses sabots

Using "à" for a possessive "de" is familiar, and even sounds a bit childish (which can be expected in a *comptine):

> le jouet à mon frère
>
> la voiture à mon pote

*Qu'a cassé* is a shortened, spoken form for *qui a cassé*.

In spoken, familiar language, you could hear eg *c'est qui qu'a fait fait ça ?* for *qui c'est qui a fait ça ?*

It is ambiguous whether *Nicolas* or his mother broke their clogs (personally, at the 1st reading, I rather understood it would be the mother).

Comment: I didn't have any doubt about the fact that it was the mother, until your answer prompted me to a second reading. But still, I think there's little doubt.

Comment: The usual wording is  *pour la **mère Nicolas*** colloquially meaning *Mrs Nicolas*, like *la mère Michel* or *la mère Brazier*...

Comment: @jlliagre: this should be a comment attached to the question.

Answer (score 5):

It is the particular meaning that « casser » can take in various contexts that is the cause of this problem in understanding;  avowedly, the context can at times be hard to distinguish clearly; there are two essential meanings; one can be called "agentive" (the subject carries out the action of breaking as an act issued from his/her own will); as regards the second meaning the subject is only accessory to the breaking; since we have the same thing in English let's consider a sentence in that language that makes that clear; what would you say of the sentence "She broke her leg going down the stairs."? It is the same thing in this nursery rhyme.

It seems there is another [variant](http://www.paroles.cc/chanson,scions-du-bois,19928); I copy it below;

> Scions, scions du bois,
>   Pour la mère, pour la mère,
>   Scions, scions du bois
>   Pour la mère Nicolas
>   Qui a cassé ses sabots
>   En mille morceaux.
>   Voici les morceaux!

According to this variant the tanslation is not

- "who (Nicolas's mother) broke his hooves/clogs into a thousand pieces!"

but

- "For Mother Nicolas
  Who broke her clogs<sup>1</sup>
  Into a thousand pieces.
  Here are the pieces!".

"Why is this broken clog story in a song about sawing wood?" is a question I had forgotten to consider. I'll answer it now; I wouldn't assert with absolute certitude that it is because clogs are carved out of wooden blocks and that necessarily, to make a pair of clogs two blocks of wood are needed, but the coincidence leaves little doubt as to that being the reason.

<sup>1</sup><sub>edit after reading of answer provided by [George M](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32440/17649)</sub>